# DataModel in NoSQL from multiple SQL tables

Tags: sql, json, database, mongodb, nosql

I have a database which look like this uploaded on a SQL Server :

[image: Database Schema]

And this specific scenario :

> The airport web page allows viewers to see details of an airport
>   together with the city that it serves including details such as the
>   timezone and day light savings, a list of the airlines, and a list of
>   destinations. Through other web pages it is possible to view details
>   of airlines and the routes.

I manage to export it as CSV and convert my 5 CSV (one for each table) into 5 JSON files.

I have to nest them to create collections in order to upload them on a MongoDB server.

My issue is that I have to work on a Data Model first and I am pretty confuse.
I am wondering how should I build it, I was thinking of doing 2 or maybe 3 collections :

```
Routes -> Airlines (-> Countries?)
Routes -> Airports -> Cities -> Countries
```

or

```
Routes -> Airlines -> Countries
Airports -> Cities -> Countries
Routes -> Airports
```

The thing is that I am not supposed to do a single collection about airports which nests information about the cities, airlines, and routes. While it is possible to nest everything within such a model, I have to consider the specific scenario.

My other question is about a method which will allow me to nest the data properly. I know I can do a python script or something like this, but regarding that I have to then upload my data on a MongoDB Server, I was wondering if there is a command or something that will help me to nest my data an create the architecture I want regarding my model.

Thank's a lot guys.
Cheers !

> I kinda answer my first question by myself reading again and again properly the Scenario. I will
>   have something like :
>
> ```
> Airports -> Cities -> Countries
> Routes / -> Airlines / -> Airports
> ```
>
> And I finally did a Python script to achieve the merging. If someone
>   know if it's possible to do this inside MongoDB, I am really
>   interested.
>
> Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda answer my first question by myself reading again and again properly the Scenario. I will have something like :

```
Airports -> Cities -> Countries
Routes / -> Airlines / -> Airports
```

And I finally did a Python script to achieve the merging.
If someone know if it's possible to do this inside MongoDB, I am really interested.

Thanks :)